# Shofar as daily call to prayer?

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, shofar

I remember learning that either during the first or second temple the shofar was blown as a daily call to prayer, or perhaps it was in Talmudic times. Anyone know a source for this?

Comment: Perhaps Sukkah 53b?

Comment: As DoubleAA points out: Mishnah Arakhin 2:3 and Mishnah Sukkah 5:5 are possible places to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @DoubleAA for pointing in the right direction. It directed me to a Mishnah in Sukkah, with the commentary of the Bartenura.

The Mishnah, [Sukkah 5:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.5.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> One sounds no fewer than twenty-one trumpet blasts in the Temple, and one sounds no more than forty-eight. The mishna elaborates: Each day there were twenty-one trumpet blasts in the Temple: Three blasts were sounded for the opening of the gates in the morning, nine for the daily morning offering, and nine for the daily afternoon offering, totaling twenty-one.

[Ovadiah MiBartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/topics/ovadiah-bartenura?tab=popular-writing-of) was an Italian rabbi, banker, Mishnaic commentator and community leader. He's known as the Bartenura. In his [commentary on this Mishnah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.5.5?lang=bi&with=Bartenura&lang2=en), he explains that on different occasions, they would sound the shofar. This happend when:

- When they open the gates of the courtyard
- when they would offer the daily libations (and during each period the Kohanim would sound the Shofar)
- the first Tekiah [in order to] suspend [from working] the people that are in the fields
  *the second Tekiah [caused] that the shutters would be removed and the stores would be locked
  *and at the third Tekiah, he removed what had to be removed and hid what had to be hidden what had been warmed and they kindled the candles.

The [English explanation of the Mishnah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.5.5?lang=bi&with=English%20Explanation%20of%20Mishnah&lang2=en) further elaborates:

> Every day there were twenty-one blasts in the Temple, three at the opening of the gates, nine at the morning tamid sacrifice, and nine at the evening tamid sacrifice. On normal days there were twenty-one blasts. There were three blasts in the morning to announce the opening of the Temple gates, and then nine blasts at each of the two daily sacrifices, the morning tamid and the afternoon tamid.

Answer (score -1):

Others may know more, but I could find no basis for your recollection. Are you thinking of every day (except Sabbaths) [during the month of Elul](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/2306683/jewish/Shofar-During-the-Month-of-Elul-How-and-Why.htm)? It is blown as a daily reminder to repent and prepare for the High Holidays.

> The month of Elul is a month of preparation for Rosh Hashanah and Yom
> Kippur. That’s why Jews blow the shofar (almost) every day of the
> month. The optimum shofar-blowing time is right after morning
> services, when everyone is still together. Missed it? You might still
> want to catch a shofar-blowing some time before sundown.1 We blow the
> shofar every day other than Shabbat, starting from Elul 1 and ending
> on Elul 28. We do not blow on Elul 29, the day before Rosh Hashanah.

Comment: The OP is not asking for the Shofar blasting during the month Elul, rather to a daily blast of the shofar as a call for prayer.

Comment: I understand, but the asker expressed uncertainty, and there does not seem to be another explanation. I'll include a disclaimer.